# Create a map variable in dataweave script with key and value from payload

Tags: mule, dataweave

How can i create a map variable in dataweavescript where the key and value are from payload
%var keyValueMap = payload map {payload.key:payload.value}

Answer (score 1):

Try this following code:

```
 %var keyValueMap= ({(payload map { ($.key): $ })})
```

I hope this will help!